# Compiz's memory utilization increasing

Tags: compiz, memory-usage, memory-leak

I have been running Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit, on my AMD desktop for quite some time. Last few days, I have been seeing the memory utilization of compiz to be increasing. I normally do not shut down the computer, however, recently the memory utilization when no apps are running is about 1 GB. I started observing and maintaining memory utilization for various apps in the system monitor and compiz seems to be utilizing ~ 90 MB. When I checked it last about 24 hours ago, it was about 86 MB and when the computer reboots, it is about 84 MB. So clearly compiz is consuming more memory when the PC is running continuously.

This PC is a generic PC @ home used for emails (Thunderbird), browsing (Mozilla Firefox), Chat (Skype, Empathy - Facebook, SIP, Gtalk, hotmail), Youtube, Shotwell for managing pictures and Rhythmbox for music. - Basically an ordinary user. No development or graphics software used.

Hardware configuration: AMD Athlon 260 Dual Core 3.2 Ghz, 4 GB RAM, 64 GB SSD for OS and 1 TB Sata for data, ASUS MoBo with on board default graphics card being used, Dell 24 " Monitor.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.01, 64 bit, all latest patches installed.

Any help is gr8.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter:

```
unity --replace &
```

This should drop it down to less memory usage.

Comment: I think this is reasonable advice, but can you expand it to explain precisely why you think it will help?

Comment: Hey thanks Mina. This works well. But any reason, why this keeps increasing?

Comment: This should work because a new instance of Unity (and thus Compiz) will be run which will kill the old process and clear all of the memory taken by this process. This includes the leaked memory.